# Why app cannot send a voice to speakers in real time?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

Application does not opens.

I am actaully new to Android Dev and also I didn't work a lot with threads. I don't really know how start(), release() and stop() works and I couldn't find info about using buffers instead of directories. Is it even possible to send voice from micro buffer to speakers ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaRecorder micro = null;
private MediaPlayer speakers = null;
private ByteBuffer audioBuffer;
private String bufferString = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
File buffer = new File(bufferString);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
    micro = new MediaRecorder();
    speakers = new MediaPlayer();

    startRecording();
}

private void startRecording(){
    micro.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    micro.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    micro.setOutputFile(buffer);
    micro.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    speakers.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        micro.prepare();
        speakers.setDataSource(bufferString);
        speakers.prepare();
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                micro.start();
                speakers.stop();
                micro.release();
                speakers.start();
            }
        }
    };
}

}
```

I tried to create app that is directly and in realtime is transferring voice from micro to speakers.

Comment: Use an `AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack` instead. Or something like Oboe or OpenSL ES.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but there will be massive mic feedback, unless you take some steps to isolate the mic from the speakers (like by using headphones).